# vscode snippets: repeat what's being typed into given location on the snippet body

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to know if I can repeat whats being typed on position $1 into the snippet location shown below:

```
"BootstrapCol": {
        "prefix": "BSCol",
        "body": [
            "<div class="col-$1">$0</div><!-- ./col-{REPEAT WHAT IS BEING TYPED HERE} -->"
        ],
        "description": "Create a Bootstrap Grid col Markup"
    }
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```json
"<div class=\"col-${1}\">$0</div><!-- ./col-${1} -->"
```

Comment: Just awesome. Thank you!